# How to play a video with Gstreamer in an endless loop?

Tags: gstreamer, embedded-linux, yocto

I want to play a video on an embedded linux device in an infinite loop using Gstreamer. Playing the video using the command

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/weston/video.mp4
```

works.

Is there any possibility to use playbin playing the video in an endless loop?

I have tried to extend the command with the following, but it did not work.

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/weston/video.mp4 loop=true
```